# How to implement a custom non-trainable PCA layer on Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, pca, layer

I am trying to develop a non-trainable custom PCA layer, where, starting from a float input of size equal to 256, the output is a two-dimensional vector obtained from the PCA application inside the network as last level. Prior to this layer I need to have one Dense layer. Below is my PCA implementation via tensorflow and the custom level:

```
class TF_PCA:
    def __init__(self, X):
        self.X = X
        self.u = None
        self.singular_values = None
        self.sigma = None

    def fit(self):
        # Perform SVD
        self.singular_values, self.u, _ = tf.linalg.svd(self.X)

        # Create sigma matrix
        self.sigma = tf.linalg.diag(self.singular_values)

    def reduce(self, n_dimensions=None, keep_info=None):
        if keep_info:
            # Normalize singular values
            normalized_singular_values = self.singular_values / sum(self.singular_values)

            # Create the aggregated ladder of kept information per dimension
            ladder = np.cumsum(normalized_singular_values)

            # Get the first index which is above the given information threshold
            index = next(idx for idx, value in enumerate(ladder) if value >= keep_info) + 1
            n_dimensions = index

        # Cut out the relevant part from sigma
        sigma = tf.slice(self.sigma, [0, 0], [self.X.shape[1], n_dimensions])

        # PCA
        pca = tf.matmul(self.u, sigma)
        return pca
```

```
class CustomPCALayer(tf.keras.layers.Layer):
  def __init__(self, num_outputs):
    super(CustomPCALayer, self).__init__()
    self.num_outputs = num_outputs
    self.total = tf.Variable(initial_value=tf.zeros((num_outputs,)), trainable=False)

  def call(self, inputs):
    tf_pca = TF_PCA(inputs)
    tf_pca.fit()
    pca = tf_pca.reduce(n_dimensions=self.num_outputs)
    return tf.convert_to_tensor(pca, dtype=tf.float32)
```

Once I implemented this I also implemented the neural network:

```
in_dim = (256,)
out_dim = 2

def build_network(inputs, out_dim):
  x = Dense(256)(inputs)
  x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
  x = CustomPCALayer(out_dim)(x)  # non-trainable layer
  return x

inputs = Input(shape=in_dim)
network = build_network(inputs, out_dim)
model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[network], name="network")

opt = keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.0001)

model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, 
              loss="mse", 
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.CosineSimilarity()])
```

As input and output I have something like this:

```
x = tf.random.uniform((300, 256))
y = tf.random.uniform((300, 2))
```

If I try to train, it immediately fails with the error *NotImplementedError: SVD gradient has not been implemented for input with unknown inner matrix shape.*

I would like to understand what is wrong with my architecture in order to solve the error and have a non-trainable layer to perform PCA

Comment: The gradient backpropagation apparently tries to go through the `tf.linalg.svd`, judging from the error message this gradient is only defined for specific tensor-shapes. Especially when using python objects (as the TF_PCA), tensorflow runs into issues when infering tensorshapes. Could you try to refactor the procedure of using `TF_PCA` a single  function and decorate is with `@tf.function`? If this is not intendeted you could use a `tf.stop_gradient` around the `tf_pca.fit()` call to prevent the backpropagation.

Comment: Additionally in the `TF_PCA.reduce()` function the call to `np.cumsum()` is likely to cause problems with gradient backpropagation. This could be replaced with `tf.math.cumsum()`. Allthough, in your case it might work anyway.

Comment: Thanks for your respose, I tried both your methods, with @tf.function the error remains the same, if instead I also use tf.stop_gradient, the new error obtained is the following: * ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: (['dense_37 / kernel: 0', 'dense_37 / bias: 0'],) * on the first level Dense

Comment: Just realized a conceptual mistake. You pass a vector of shape `(#batch, 256)` into `tf.linalg.svd` operation, where the batch dimension is `None` to allow for dynamic batch-size. SVD is implemented with gradients for square matrices of known size. I am not sure if it is reasonable to compute the svd like this.

Comment: probably [tft.pca](https://www.tensorflow.org/tfx/transform/api_docs/python/tft/pca) suits you (in order not to create it manually)